# Apache reverse proxy and redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

We're using apache httpd, to do a reverse proxy to another service running on another port.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location /tull>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass https://myserver.com:8446/tbl/tbl
            ProxyPassReverse https://myserver.com:8446/tbl/tbl
</Location>
```

The service running at :8446/tbl/tbl does a redirect to it self.
Thus, if I do this using the proxy:

```
https://myserver.com/tull
```

When the service does a redirect to it self, it goes to:

```
https://myserver.com/tbl/tbl
```

What I wanted it to do, was a redirect to:

```
https://myserver.com/tull
```

Thus, the question becomes - Can I somehow configure apache httpd to do a reverse proxy to myserver.com:8446/tbl/tbl, but at the same time make the 8446-service think the original request is /tull ?

Cheers

Comment: i'm not a apache expert, but i think you missing something in your proxypass directive, try with "ProxyPass /tull https://myserver.com:8446/tbl/tbl" and "ProxyPassReverse /tull https://myserver.com:8446/tbl/tbl"

Comment: It's not the issue, but thanks for trying to help :) The reason why there's no /tull in the directives, is because it's all wrapped in a Location-tag. Adding /tull as well will result in an config-error on apache-restart

Comment: Well, to make the backend think the request is for `/tull`, all it uses is the requested URL, which is being explicitly set to `/tbl/tbl` instead of `/tull` - can you clarify what you want the request to the backend to look like?

Comment: I want to a request to /tull to be reverse proxied to /tbl/tbl in such a way that the service at /tbl/tbl would still regard /tull to be the URL it was asked for. Something I initially thought ProxyPreserveHost would fix...but obviously not